# Update gridview in viewpager

Tags: android, gridview, android-viewpager

I have been searching for a while for a way to refresh a gridview within a viewpager and I am yet to find an answer. More specificaly my problem is that I have a view pager with three gridviews. Each gridview is populated by an arraylist and if the arraylist is changed the gridview stays the same. How can I make it update? I have tried calling notifydatasetchange on the adapter and that doesnt help.

here is my code for the view pager adapter

```
public class FavoritesViewPager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {     
    public FavoritesViewPager(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        UserDatabaseHandler UDH = new UserDatabaseHandler(getActivity());
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            ArrayList<Exercise> strengthList = UDH.getFavoriteExercises("strengthexercises");
            UDH.close();
            return FavoriteExercises.newInstance(strengthList);
        case 1:
            ArrayList<Exercise> stretchList = UDH.getFavoriteExercises("stretchingexercises");
            UDH.close();
            return FavoriteExercises.newInstance(stretchList);
        case 2:
            ArrayList<Exercise> warmupList = UDH.getFavoriteExercises("warmupexercises");
            UDH.close();
            return FavoriteExercises.newInstance(warmupList);
        default:
            ArrayList<Exercise> temp = UDH
                    .getFavoriteExercises("warmupexercises");
            UDH.close();
            return FavoriteExercises.newInstance(temp);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your pager has only two pages, you should use FragmentPagerAdapter. You can get the fragment by findFragmentByTag then call update method of this fragment.

```
String fragmentName = makeFragmentName(_viewPager.getId(), i);
Fragment frag = _fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentName);
private static String makeFragmentName(int viewId, int index) {
    return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + index;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I mean a few pages